# Get selected values of a ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, entity-framework-6.1, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Model:

```
public virtual ICollection<Product> OriginalProducts { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Product> SimilarProducts { get; set; }
```

View (Create and Edit are equal):

```
<div id="divSimilar" class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Similar Products", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ListBox("Products", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MyAttributes")] Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Products.Add(product);
        List<string> selectedSimilars = Request.Form.GetValues("Products").ToList();

        foreach (string Id in selectedSimilars)
        {
            Product similarProd = db.Products.Find(System.Convert.ToInt32(Id));
            if (similarProd != null)
                product.SimilarProducts.Add(similarProd);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index").Success("Successfully created");
    }

    ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(db.Products, "Id", "Name", product.SimilarProducts);
    return View(product);
}

public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(db.Products.Where(p => p.Id != product.Id), "Id", "Name", product.SimilarProducts);
    return View(product);
}
```

So, since "Create" part is working fine, I want to know how can I make to get all selected SimilarProducts (that I added in "Create") in my "Edit" view. What changes are necessary in controller to make it work?

Btw, since I'm using the ListBox, I think there's a different way of the DropDownList, because I used this way for all my DropDownLists and are working fine.

**EDIT**

I want to display in "Edit" view, all products (that were selected when I created that product) in blue. In other words, the ActionResult "Edit" should get all selected products from the SimilarProducts list, as in the DropDownList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to make it work, I'll post the solution, in case of anyone needs in the future:

```
ViewBag.Products = new MultiSelectList(db.Products.Where(p => p.Id != product.Id), "Id", "Name", product.SimilarProducts.Select(p => p.Id));
```

Little explanation:

Since I'm using ListBox, so I must use MultiSelectList, because SelectList recognizes just one item selected, its parameter is: (object selectedValue), already on MultiSelectList is: (IEnumerable selectedValues), so I changed `SelectList` to `MultiSelectList` and added it: `.Select(p => p.Id))` into my ActionResult "Edit".

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox` Control may have multiple selected `Items` (thus, multiple different values) as demonstrated in the following code snippet (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private void SelectedItems(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (lb.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        label1.Content = "Has " + (lb.SelectedItems.Count.ToString()) + " item(s) selected.";
    }
}
```

You should specify the business logic for finding the Item in the selection (e.g., first in the selection). But, if selection mode is set to `Single` you may use the property `SelectedItem`.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Well, I think you don't understood the question, I want to display in "Edit" view, all products (that were selected) in blue, by default, got it? "Edit" controller should get all selected products from the SimilarProducts list.
As in DropDownList, when I go to my Edit View, comes the selected value that I selected when I create it. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: The answer was given pertinent to the title of your question ("Get selected values of a ListBox"). Please do not confuse the functional spec with valid question: just clarify the problematic part of your code, otherwise it looks like a request for code-writing service. Thanks and regards,

Comment: I edited, writing everything I wrote here, what didn't you understand..? What is the difference of what I wrote here for the title?
Regards.

Comment: Man, I already posted all my code, and you posted a solution using WebForms. As you could see, I'm using MVC, so I can't use your solution, and 'Get selected values of a ListBox' is a title, so as every title, it should be just a summary. The other explanations are in the end of the post, as you and any other can see.